# The least non-negative residue of $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p-1}\pmod{p^2}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number. Find the least non-negative residue
>   $$1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{p-1}\pmod{p^2}$$

I think this is a good problem. Thank you everyone.

Comment: I think that saying "I think this is a good problem" and saying "thanks" are both nice things to do, but that they are not a substitute for explaining your thoughts and attempts on the problem.

Comment: oh,Thank you,sorry,My English is very poor

Comment: $$(p-1)!(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{p-1})\equiv 0 \text{ mod } p^2$$

Answer (score 2):

By [Wolstenholme's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem), that sum is zero mod $p^2$. EDIT: if $p\gt3$ (thanks, Chris).

Comment: If $p>3{}{}{}{}$